# Resources to learn KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I have to work on an existing KnockoutJS project. I am trying to learn it by myself from KnockoutJS website and other places but having a hard time. Could you please guide me some good resources to get hang of it? Also, if there is any one to one help available on the web please let me know.

Comment: Work through the [tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) on the main Knockout site and come back if you have specific questions. But be sure you have a solid understanding of JavaScript first.

Comment: Do you need to combine it with specific technology (like .Net MVC or PHP)? If so, I recommend Pluralsight tutorials, they offer 0-100 knowledge really fast.

Answer (score -1):

The best place to look for would be [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/).
If you fully understood all the basic tutorials then all you need to do is to head to their Documentation page and search in the docs for what you need to learn/do.
Everything that knockout is capable of is in there, i would suggest going through all of them at least once,they are easy to understand as long as you have a solid knowledge of Javascript (as JohnyHK suggested)

Comment: I have done JavaScript tutorials from W3Schools and Codecademy but don't have much practical experience. How much in-depth knowledge of JavaScript is required?